# Can transformable attributes in Core Data entities be pointers to c structs? My transformer is not being called

Tags: objective-c, core-data, pointers, struct, nsvaluetransformer

I'm trying to make a CoreData-persisted entity.  This entity has a few properties, one of which is a non-standard attribute, state.  The state attribute is a pointer to a C struct with a few properties in it.  Here's what my data model looks like:

Entities:

**MDInstance**

Attributes:

- duration: Integer 16
- moves: Integer 16
- name: String
- state: Transformable.  I set the Transformer to MDStateTransformer.

I generated my class and edited the state property. This is what the interface looks like:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "MDState.h" // this is where the State structure is defined

@interface MDInstance : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * duration;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * moves;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic) State *state; // note that this is a pointer to a struct

@end
```

This is what the implementation looks like:

```
#import "MDInstance.h"

@implementation MDGameInstance

@dynamic duration;
@dynamic moves;
@dynamic name;

@synthesize state;

@end
```

I created a value transformer called MDStateTransformer.  The implementation of this is (probably) not important.  Suffice it to say I have `allowsReverseTransformation` returning `YES`, `transformedValueClass` returning `[NSValue class]`, and I've implemented `transformedValue:` and `reverseTransformedValue:`

Lastly, I registered the MDStateTransformer in my AppDelegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` like this:

```
MDStateTransformer *transformer = [[MDStateTransformer alloc] init];
[NSValueTransformer setValueTransformer:transformer forName:@"MDStateTransformer"];
```

If I create a new instance of my MDInstance, set it's attribute -including the state attribute- and then try to save the entity, my transformer is never called.

I put a stop point in my transformer's init method and it is being instantiated.  I put another in `transformedValue:` and it the function is not being called.

However, if I update my MDInstance so that the state attribute is not a pointer, but is simply a State structure, and I update the transformer to work with a struct and not a pointer, the `transformedValue:` is called.

Is it possible to have a custom attribute on an object which is a pointer to a c struct?  If so, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your transformable attribute also needs to be specified as `@dynamic` and not `@synthesize` in your implementation file. By synthesizing that property you provide an getter and setter outside of core data and thus the Core Data provided accessors will not be used.

Comment: I'm not sure this is quite correct.  I made this change and I see the following output when I run my unit tests: CoreData: error: Property 'setState:' is a scalar type on class 'MDGameInstance' that does not match its Entity's property's scalar type.  "Dynamically generated accessors do not support implicit type coercion.  Cannot generate a setter method for it."  Since this is a scalar, maybe I need to write my own get/set functions?  And if so, I'm not sure how do this properly for CoreData.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I guess that means that you can not use a C struct pointer with a `NSValueTransformer` in Core Data. You’ll have to do the conversion yourself in a custom getter and setter. Take a look at this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html